# 勉強で得意だったのは、国語と社会で、苦手だったのは、数学と理科でした。

Tags: meaning

勉強で得意だったのは、国語と社会で、苦手だったのは、数学と理科でした。

Can anyone explain what that second で is doing here? ( This one 国語と社会で )
From what I can surmise there are 2 separate subject, good subjects and bad subjects, why on god's green earth are they using a で to separate them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The で is the continuative form (連用形) of the assertive auxiliary (断定の助動詞), or "copula", だ/です. Your sentence can be rewritten like this:

> 勉強で得意だったのは、国語と社会**でした**。(そして、) 苦手だったのは、数学と理科でした。

(でした is the past form of です, as you know.)

---

Take these sentences for example:

> 朝ごはんは、ご飯とみそ汁**です**。お昼ごはんは、カレーライスとサラダです。

You can combine them by turning the です into the continuative form で:

> 朝ごはんは、ご飯とみそ汁**で**、お昼ごはんは、カレーライスとサラダです。

Turning the whole sentence into the past tense, you have:

> 朝ごはんは、ご飯とみそ汁で、お昼ごはんは、カレーライスとサラダ**でした**。

Now I believe you can see how your sentence is structured.

Comment: Alternatively, it could have been *...であり*、 correct?

Comment: @rych, Grammatically, yes. (But であり would sound more literary, as you may know.)